# How can I test that a method has been called during runtime with minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

How can I test the fact that `Geokit::Geocoders::MultiGeocoder.geocode(generate_address)` was called only after a save. Should I write my code differently?

Please, Help.

`

https://gist.github.com/bennacer860/b67583afee1bb9255938a3a621a80a54

```
class Playspace < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :geocode_address, on: [:create, :update]

  def geocode_address
     geo = Geokit::Geocoders::MultiGeocoder.geocode(generate_address)
    # puts geo
    if geo.success
      self.lat = geo.lat
      self.lng = geo.lng
      self.state_code = geo.state_code
      self.country_code = geo.country_code
      self.geolocated_at = Time.now.utc
    else
     errors.add(:address, "Could not Geocode address #{generate_address}") 
    end
 end

  def did_address_change?
    %w( address city state_code country_code postal_code lat lng  ).each do |column|
      return true if (self.send("#{column}_changed?"))
    end
    false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend mocking out your external API calls with [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr). In fact, the gem you are using in the code uses VCR for its [own test suite](https://github.com/geokit/geokit/blob/ddd4130b6cb79faeb504a00a88735936ecda3876/test/test_base_geocoder.rb#L43-L45).

Once you have VCR setup in your tests, they might contain something like this:

```
VCR.use_cassette("geocode") do
  playspace.geocode_address
  # Check that one of the columns changed
  assert playspace.did_address_change?
end
```